# How to handle nested double quotes in Nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi, cloudera

We have a csv file with nested double quotes column.

For example : 1,John,26,"how are you "Jim"".

In this example we have 4 columns id, name, age and message.

Here message column is having nested double quotes, which is causing the data parsing issue in **convertRecord** Nifi processor(**could not parse incoming data error**). Is there any way we can escape nested double quotes and read the data properly ?

As shown in the below image, we are using the following properties in both CSVReader and CSVRecordSetWritter controller services.

[image: :]

Comment: It's not a valid csv format. Normally double-quote must be escaped with another double-quote... So, better to solve this issue at the place where csv is produced.

Comment: Unfortunately we can not alter the source and correct the data. Need to find a way in Nifi only.

Comment: How you could detect which quote is the end of the field? If you have such a field as a last one - then it's possible to use scripting to fix format.

Comment: @dagget Right now we changed the file format from CSV to tab delimited file and changed the Quote Character property in controller service from double quote to a non English Character. As of now the data is getting parsed properly with this changes.

Answer (score 0):

We had the exact same issue and as @daggett highlighted - How could you detect which quote is the end of the field? We even spoke with Cloudera, and everything boils down to that data does not conform to CSV standard rules.

So written a small python script which is called using `ExecuteScript` processor, and able to escape almost all the special characters except when double quote and dilimiter is part of the data eg. `"field_1","field_2 this is very invalid", data","field_3"`

Give it a go and please comment if it works so that we can encompass logic into a custom processor!

```py
from org.apache.commons.io import IOUtils
from java.nio.charset import StandardCharsets
from org.apache.nifi.processor.io import StreamCallback
from org.apache.nifi.processors.script import ExecuteScript
from org.python.core.util.FileUtil import wrap
from io import StringIO
import re


# Define a subclass of StreamCallback for use in session.write()
class PyStreamCallback(StreamCallback):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def process(self, inputStream, outputStream):
        with wrap(inputStream) as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
            outer_new_value_list = []
            is_header_row = True
            for row in lines:
                if is_header_row:
                    is_header_row = False
                    outer_new_value_list.append(row)
                    continue

                char_list = list(row.strip())

                for position, char in enumerate(char_list):
                    #print(position, char)
                    # if position == 54:
                    #     print()
                    if (position + 1) == len(char_list):
                        continue
                    if position == 0:
                        continue
                    else:
                        if char == '"':
                            if char_list[position - 1] == ',' or char_list[position + 1] == ',':
                                # this double quote is Quote Character at start of field or end of field
                                continue
                            if char_list[position - 1] != ',' and char_list[position + 1] != ',':
                                # this double quote is inbetween and is not Quote Character, add  escape character to it
                                replace_char = '\\' + char
                                char_list[position] = replace_char
                        if char == ',':
                            # Int values are not in double quotes, so check previous and next char is of int type
                            previous_char_type = ''
                            next_char_type = ''
                            try:
                                previous_char = char_list[position - 1]
                                if isinstance(int(previous_char), int):
                                    previous_char_type = 'Int'
                            except:
                                pass
                                # print('previous_char : ' + str(previous_char))

                            try:
                                next_char = char_list[position + 1]
                                if isinstance(int(next_char), int):
                                    next_char_type = 'Int'
                            except:
                                pass
                            # print(" next_char: " + str(next_char))

                            if previous_char_type == 'Int' or next_char_type == 'Int':
                                print('No need to replace this instance of comma')
                                continue

                            if char_list[position - 1] == '"' or char_list[position + 1] == '"':
                                # delimited comma
                                continue
                            if char_list[position - 1] != '"' and char_list[position + 1] != '"':
                                # not delimited comma, inbetween comma, add with escape character to it
                                replace_char = '\\' + char
                                char_list[position] = replace_char
                        if char == '\\':
                            replace_char = ''
                            char_list[position] = replace_char

                new_data_line = ''.join([str(elem) for elem in char_list])
                outer_new_value_list.append(new_data_line + '\r\n')

            with wrap(outputStream, 'w') as filehandle:
                filehandle.writelines("%s" % line for line in outer_new_value_list)


# end class
flowFile = session.get()
if (flowFile != None):
    flowFile = session.write(flowFile, PyStreamCallback())
    session.transfer(flowFile, ExecuteScript.REL_SUCCESS)
# implicit return at the end
```

Comment: thanks for your response . Right now we changed the file format from CSV to tab delimited  file and changed the Quote Character property in controller service from double quote to non English Character. As of now the data is getting parsed properly with this changes.